# Mvc 4 JsonResult not returning anything

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this action on a Items controller

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Search(string data, int id)
{
    var date = DateTime.Now;
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        date = DateTime.Parse(data);
    var result = Repository.FindBy(date, id); // (1)
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and I'm calling it with jQuery

```
function successHandler(success){
    console.log(success); // (2)
    return success;
}

function errorHandler(error){
    console.error(error); // (3)
    return error;
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '/Items/Date/2015-01-01/Id/2',
}).then(successHandler, errorHandler);
```

If I put a breakpoint in (1) and launch the jQuery ajax call the debugger hits the breakpoint, I can see that `result` is a valid `IEnumerable<Item>` and that the Action returns.

If I put a breakpoint in (2) it's never hit, and in (3) the value of `error` is

```
{ readyState: 4,
  responseText: "",
  status: 200,
  statusText: "OK" }
```

Which is not an error.

If I call directly the URL (`http://localhost:26252/Items/Search/2015-01-01/Id/2`) I get an empty page and, using Firebug's console, the same response.

What is going on?

EDIT:

the custom route for this action is

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Items",
    url: "Items/Date/{date}/Id/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Items", action = "Search" }
);
```

and the default is

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: side question: what kind of javascript is that? Did the brackets just disappear, or is that some kind of parser?

Comment: it's coffeescript. would you prefer for me to paste the compiled version?

Comment: yes. please post the generated js. Also do you have a custom route template for your action method ?

Comment: Do you ahave a custom route pattern setup for this action method to match with the url you are calling ? What is the status of this ajax request in your browser dev tools network tab ? Also what is the response coming back ?

Comment: The "response that I get from the console" is the HTTP header, and it's the same of the JSON that I put in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work fine as long as result variable value is a valid object/collection. Your ajax call will go to the error callback if it receives `null` response from the server where it is expecting a json data structure as the response. Since jQuery could not conver the `null` value to a valid json, you are getting this error.

Make sure your action method is not returning a `null` value. If it returns a collection, you should return an empty collection when there is no data, I personally prefer to wrap the response in another wrapper response to handle this kind of situation.

```
var result = Repository.FindBy(date, id);    
return Json(new { status="success", data=result } , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This will return a JSON structure like this

```
{
  "status":"success",
  "data": null // or a valid object/array here
}
```

Now in your success handler you access the `data` property after null check.

```
successHandler = function (response) {
       if(response.status==="success")
       { 
          if(response.data!=null)
          {
            console.log(success);
            return success;
          }
          else
          {
            console.log('data is null. may be no data for your filter');
          }
       }
};
```

Also, you might consider using `DateTime?` type for your parameter instead of reading the value in string and parsing it again.